# Nextflow - Multiqc process per sample instead of processing all the samples output together

Tags: groovy, nextflow

My current workflow generate one multiqc report for all the samples in the input list, for some reason I want to generate multiqc report per sample instead.
Here's my current workflow..MULTIQC process...Appreciate any help.
The input could be either `bam` or `cram` format files
`input.yaml`

```
samples:
-
 biosample_id: NA12878-chr14-AKT1
 aln: NA12878-chr14-AKT1.bam
-
 biosample_id: NA12878-chr14-AKT2
 aln: NA12878-chr14-AKT2.bam
```

`main.nf`

```
Channel
        .empty()
        .mix( mosdepth_bam.out.dists )
        .mix( mosdepth_bam.out.summary )
        .mix( mosdepth_cram.out.dists )
        .mix( mosdepth_cram.out.summary )
        .mix( mosdepth_datamash.out.coverage )
        .mix( verifybamid2_bam.out.freemix )
        .mix( verifybamid2_cram.out.freemix )
        .mix( verifybamid2_bam.out.ancestry )
        .mix( verifybamid2_cram.out.ancestry )
        .mix( samtools_stats_bam.out )
        .mix( samtools_stats_cram.out )
        .map { sample, files -> files }
        .collect()
        .set { log_files }

    multiqc( log_files )
```

`modules/multiqc/main.nf`

```
process multiqc {

input:
path 'data/*'

output:
path "multiqc_report.html", emit: report
path "multiqc_data", emit: data
path "multiqc_data/multiqc_data.json", emit: json_data

"""
multiqc \\
    --data-format json \\
    --enable-npm-plugin \\
    .
"""
}
```

I tried the below for multiqc process to report per sample...

Try 1.
`main.nf`

```
Channel
    samples.map { it.biosample_id }
    .set { sample_ids }

multiqc( sample_ids, samtools_stats_bam.out.stats.mix( samtools_stats_cram.out.stats, mosdepth_bam.out.dists, mosdepth_bam.out.summary, mosdepth_cram.out.dists, mosdepth_cram.out.summary, mosdepth_datamash.out.coverage, verifybamid2_bam.out.freemix, verifybamid2_cram.out.freemix, verifybamid2_bam.out.ancestry, verifybamid2_cram.out.ancestry, ).collect() )
```

`modules/multiqc/main.nf`

```
process multiqc {

    tag { sample }

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path('*')
  output:
   
  tuple val(sample), path("${sample}/multiqc_report.html"), emit: report
  tuple val(sample), path("${sample}/multiqc_data"), emit: data
  tuple val(sample), path("${sample}/multiqc_data/multiqc_data.json"), emit: json_data

  """
  multiqc \\
    --data-format json \\
    --enable-npm-plugin \\
    -o ${sample} \\
    .
  """
}
```

**Attached the full workflow generate single multiqc report, just in case** `main.nf` file..

```
// main

workflow {

ref_fasta = file( params.reference )
ref_fasta_idx = file( params.reference + ".fai" )
autosomes_non_gap_regions = file( params.autosomes_non_gap_regions )
vbi2_ud = file( params.vbi2_ud )
vbi2_bed = file( params.vbi2_bed )
vbi2_mean = file( params.vbi2_mean )

inputs = new YamlSlurper().parse(file(params.inputs_list))

Channel
    .fromList(inputs['samples'])
    .ifEmpty { ['biosample_id': params.biosample_id, 'aln': params.aln] }
    .set { samples }

Channel
    samples.branch { rec ->
        def aln_file = rec.aln ? file( rec.aln ) : null

        bam: rec.biosample_id && aln_file?.extension == 'bam'
            def bam_idx = file( "${rec.aln}.bai" )

            return tuple( rec.biosample_id, aln_file, bam_idx )

        cram: rec.biosample_id && aln_file?.extension == 'cram'
            def cram_idx = file( "${rec.aln}.crai" )

            return tuple( rec.biosample_id, aln_file, cram_idx )
    }
    .set { aln_inputs }


samtools_stats_bam( aln_inputs.bam, [] )
samtools_stats_cram( aln_inputs.cram, ref_fasta )

verifybamid2_bam( aln_inputs.bam, ref_fasta, vbi2_ud, vbi2_bed, vbi2_mean )
verifybamid2_cram( aln_inputs.cram, ref_fasta, vbi2_ud, vbi2_bed, vbi2_mean )

mosdepth_bam( aln_inputs.bam, [] )
mosdepth_cram( aln_inputs.cram, ref_fasta )

Channel
    .empty()
    .mix( mosdepth_bam.out.regions )
    .mix( mosdepth_cram.out.regions )
    .set { mosdepth_regions }

mosdepth_datamash( mosdepth_regions, autosomes_non_gap_regions )
//    mosdepth_datamash( autosomes_non_gap_regions, mosdepth_bam.out.regions.mix( mosdepth_cram.out.regions ) )


Channel
    .empty()
    .mix( mosdepth_bam.out.dists )
    .mix( mosdepth_bam.out.summary )
    .mix( mosdepth_cram.out.dists )
    .mix( mosdepth_cram.out.summary )
    .mix( mosdepth_datamash.out.coverage )
    .mix( verifybamid2_bam.out.freemix )
    .mix( verifybamid2_cram.out.freemix )
    .mix( verifybamid2_bam.out.ancestry )
    .mix( verifybamid2_cram.out.ancestry )
    .mix( samtools_stats_bam.out )
    .mix( samtools_stats_cram.out )
    .map { sample, files -> files }
    .collect()
    .set { log_files }

multiqc( log_files )


Channel
    samples.map { it.biosample_id }
    .set { sample_ids }

compile_metrics ( sample_ids, multiqc.out.json_data )    
}
```

**Attached one of the module for ref** `modules/mosdepth/main.nf`

```
process mosdepth {

    tag { sample }

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(bam), path(bai)
    path ref_fasta

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("*.regions.bed.gz"), emit: regions
    tuple val(sample), path("*.dist.txt"), emit: dists
    tuple val(sample), path("*.summary.txt"), emit: summary

    script:
    def fasta = ref_fasta ? /--fasta "${ref_fasta}"/ : ''

    """
   # run mosdepth    
   # do not output per-base depth and apply 1000bp window-sizes
   # use the reads with mapping quality 20 and above

    mosdepth \\
        --no-per-base \\
        --by 1000 \\
        --mapq 20 \\
        --threads ${task.cpus} \\
        ${fasta} \\
        "${sample}" \\
        "${bam}"
    """
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to see what's going on as you're only providing the `main.nf` and `modules/multiqc/main.nf` files. And there appear to be input cardinality errors in the scripts, but I got a little lost trying to go over your examples. Regardless, there are a few suggestions I can make.

Importantly, by not joining output streams using the `join` [operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join), you're risking incorrect sample IDs being paired with data from different files. I believe nextflow randomly allocates data to processes when more than one item is ready in a given channel.

The easiest solution would be to collect and join all data emitted from mosdepth, verifybamid2, and samtools. I don't use any of these tools, so I'll make up the tuple in the examples.

modepth:

```
output:
tuple, val("$sampleID"), path("${sampleID}_bam.dists"), path("${sampleID}_bam.summary"), emit: mosdepth_bam_out
```

samtools:

```
output:
tuple, val("$sampleID"), path("${sampleID}_bam.stats"), emit: samtools_bam_out
```

verifybamid2:

```
output:
tuple, val("$sampleID"), path("${sampleID}_bam.freemix"), path("${sampleID}_bam.ancestry"), emit: verifybamid_bam_out
```

Workflow `main.nf`

```
// Some of the processes just as an example
samtools_stats_bam( aln_inputs.bam, [] )
verifybamid2_bam( aln_inputs.bam, ref_fasta, vbi2_ud, vbi2_bed, vbi2_mean )
mosdepth_bam( aln_inputs.bam, [] )

samtools_stats_bam
  .out
  .samtools_bam_out
  .collect() 
  .join( verifybamid2_bam.out.verifybamid_bam_out.collect(), by: 0 )
  .set { intermediate_ch1 } // I am unsure if you can string multiple joins together. Hence the intermediate channel.

intermediate_ch1
  .join( mosdepth_bam.out.mosdepth_bam_out.collect(), by: 0 )
  .set { multiqc_in }

multiqc( multiqc_in )
```

You'd also need to update the multiqc input cardinality to reflect your joined input channel:

```
input:
tuple, val(sampleID), path(samtools_bam_stats), path(verify_bam_freemix), path(verify_bam_ancestry), path(mosdepth_bam_dists), path(mosdepth_bam_summary)
```

Code not tested, and you'll need to check the order in which `join` preserves, but it will be consistent, I just can't remember if the initial channel joins to the left or right.

Edit:
Also, I have never tried using the `collect` [operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collect) in the same command, so you may need to make more intermediate channels. I also don't know if it's entirely necessary. A final note is you will need to change multiqc's output file name to stop file name collisions in the output directory.